# When shall I use composite ID vs attribute / blocks in Terraform resource schemas?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Is there a guidance / rule of thumb about using composite ID vs attribute / blocks in Terraform schemas?

I.e., there's a parent resource and some child (parent-scoped) resource:

```
// main.tf
resource "environment" "test" {
  // id = "environment-12345"
  name = "test_sa"
}

# option #1
resource "account" "premium" {
  // id = "environment-12345/account-67890"
  display_name = "premium-account"
  owner_first_name = "Kyle"
  ...
}

# option #2
resource "account" "premium" {
  // id = "account-67890"
  environment_id = environment.test.id
  display_name = "premium-account"
  owner_first_name = "Kyle"
  ...
}

# option #3
resource "account" "premium" {
  // id = "account-67890"
  environment {
     id = environment.test.id
  }
  display_name = "premium-account"
  owner_first_name = "Kyle"
  ...
}
```

Which of those 3 options is recommended or something? I can't see any clear advantanges one over another. You can assume that `environmentId` is necessary for completing a `Read` operation on `account` resource instance.

Comment: Recommended by who or what, and what purpose? Naming conventions are use-case specific.

Comment: Well could you share some of these providers that use scoped resource / what ID they use?